# run openAttachment id: 5E14F03C543953911C985450FC3B120DB262DCA60961B02D8B8311D039D4FDE2

Tags: corda

Trying to download an attachment using openAttachment command and its throwing illegalArgumentExcpetion

```
Wed Sep 19 23:32:29 IST 2018>>> run openAttachment id: 5E14F03C543953911C985450FC3B120DB262DCA60961B02D8B8311D039D4FDE2
RPC failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and was fixed by https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3248. The fix will be available in Corda 4.